# Getting cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory error while run time

Tags: java, c, linux, debugging, gcc

i have successfully compiled the file but now i am getting following errors

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mcr/v717/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server/:D_LIBRARY_PATH
./invoke
./invoke: error while loading shared libraries: libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make: *** [run] Error 127
```

I have checked with library path , still getting this error. please suggest me good solution along with some conceptual information.

```
run: Prog.class invoke
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mcr/v717/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
        ./invoke
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your output more carefully:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/...blah...:D_LIBRARY_PATH
                                       ^
here-----------------------------------'
```

Make has interpreted `$L` as a make variable, and expanded it with an empty string.

The other problem is that exporting a variable from a subshell is probably ineffectual.

You need to "escape" the `$` as `$$`, and combine both into one command:

```
run: Prog.class invoke
        env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mcr/v717/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server/:$$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./invoke
```

Note: I've changed the `export` to `env`, if it's not obvious.